# Tomcat + DataSourceRealm and custom sql query (disable a user flag)?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, tomcat9

[DataSourceRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html#DataSourceRealm) does not support a customized `select user, select role` sql queries. I want to add `enabled(boolean)` sql column to enable and disable users. Is it only option to subclass and create `MuchBetterDataSourceRealm` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the startInternal method in DataSourceRealm class (at the bottom).
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/DataSourceRealm.java

There you can see how the sql is created.

Configuring the realm like this

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/myDatabase"
       userTable="usertable u"
       userNameCol="u.enabled = TRUE AND u.username"
       userCredCol="u.password"
       userRoleTable="roletable r JOIN usertable u ON r.username = u.username"
       roleNameCol="r.rolename">
</Realm>
```

results in the following statements

```
SELECT
r.rolename
FROM
roletable r JOIN usertable u ON r.username = u.username
WHERE
u.enabled = TRUE AND u.username
= ?

SELECT
u.password
FROM
usertable u
WHERE
u.enabled = TRUE AND u.username
= ?
```

Comment: Nice trick indeed.